# How to pass scope variable in ng-init using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have problem passing the variable declared from the scope to ng-init:

so far I have something like this:

```
$scope.x = '10';

<div ng-controller = "controller" ng-init="function(x)">
```

How do I pass x var from the scope inside ng-init function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A lot of people will tell you you shouldn't do this (as mentioned in the docs here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit).

As for actually doing it....

```
<div ng-controller="controller" ng-init="x = x">
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this one can help you:

```
$scope.x = '10';

<div ng-controller = "controller" ng-init="x">
```

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to push a value in using the ng-init i would use something like this

Js code

```
angular.module("app",[])
.controller("ctrl",function($scope){
    $scope.x = "this will be replaced"; //not really needed
    $scope.initialize = function(bar){
        $scope.x=bar;
    }
})
```

and html

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl" ng-init="initialize('your value')">
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to execute a function on a tag where you have a controller, why not simply run the function in the controller's constructor (i.e. function)?

Not everything has to be in the markup.

JS:

```
angular.module(...).controller('MyController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.myFunction($scope.x);
})
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="MyController"></div>
```