# Can we use variable in ng-init inside controller?

Tags: angularjs

[How to pass scope variable in ng-init using AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28770156/how-to-pass-scope-variable-in-ng-init-using-angularjs)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because: I don't understand this is question or answer, also the questioner is a human or Animal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done easily as shown below:

```
<div ng-init="data = 'This is initialized in ng-init'">
    Variable - {{data}}
</div>
```

Refer the demo [**here**](https://jsfiddle.net/shashank2691/kL63v12v/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this Code

```
$scope.test = '10';

<div ng-controller = "controller" ng-init="test">
```

or

```
<div ng-controller="controller" ng-init="test = test">
```