# ng-show not updating with $timeout function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, django

I'm trying to write my own photo slider so that the image and text I have on my Django homepage will fade from one to the next (and then repeat).

I created a timeout function to loop a $scope.current_slide variable from 1-3, and back to 1 at a set interval.

I'm using ng-show on each `<div>` so that when the $scope.current_slide variable is equal to the number of slide, each picture will appear.

The problem I'm having: The images aren't cycling through when I use the timeout function. However! I know in theory my code should work because when I make a button, and use ng-click to allow the button to increment a an angular 'click' variable (1, 2, 3, etc.) the correct pictures show up.

The pictures just don't scroll correctly with the timeout function. I added $scope.$apply() thinking this would fix it, but nothing changed.

I have the JS file within my home.html page so that it can dynamically pull the total number of slides from Django.

home.html

```
    <script>
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute', 'ui.bootstrap', 'ngAnimate']);

myApp.controller('myController', ['$scope', '$timeout', function($scope, $timeout) {


$scope.timeInMs = 0;
$scope.current_slide = 1;
// FUNCTION EXECUTES EVERY FEW SECONDS, INCREMENTS THE $scope.current_slide VARIABLE
var countUp = function() {
    $scope.timeInMs+= 2200;
    $timeout(countUp, 2200);
    $scope.current_slide += 1;
    if($scope.current_slide > sliderscount) {
    $scope.current_slide = 1;
    }
    $scope.$apply();


}

$timeout(countUp, 2200);

}]);
// This variable indicates the total number of slides we have 
var sliderscount = {{ sliders_count }};



</script>

{% for slider in sliders %}
      <div ng-init="current_slide=1" ng-show="current_slide == '{{ forloop.counter }}'" style="background-image: url('{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ slider.background_image }}');" id="bannerHome" class="container-fluid slider{{ forloop.counter }} animate-show-hide" >
        <h1 class = "bannerSlideMain">{{ slider.headline | upper }}</h1>
        <p class = "bannerSlideSub">{{ slider.subhead }}</p>
        <p><a id = "bannerButton" href = "{% url 'about-view' %}" role = "button">LEARN MORE
          <span class = "glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right" aria-hidden = "true"><span></a>
        </p>
      </div>
{% endfor %}
// WHEN CLICKED, VARIABLE UPDATES, AND PICTURES SCROLL THROUGH
<button ng-click="count = count + 1" ng-init="count=0">Hello!</button>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Looks like your `{{ forloop.counter }}` is not depends on `slider` loop variable

Comment: Ah yes, thanks for responding! You're right -- the {{ forloop.counter }} is sort of a freebie with Django. This part is actually working OK, so that {{ forloop.counter }} renders to 1 / 2 / 3, or whichever it should be.

Comment: Oh my fault... Try to move `$scope.current_slide += 1; if($scope.current_slide > sliderscount) { $scope.current_slide = 1; }` inside `$scope.$apply(function () { ... })` function

Comment: Hmm. It gives me a module injector error when I move everything inside

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I suspected, the problem was that the current_slide variable in ng-show wasn't being updated. I was able to update it by replicating this solution below: 
[How to pass scope variable in ng-init using AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28770156/how-to-pass-scope-variable-in-ng-init-using-angularjs/28770263#28770263)

I had the ng-controller declaration in a different HTML file (one that is linked by Django's 'include' template option). For some reason, if you put the ng-controller declaration in a separate HTML file, this won't work. I'd love to find out why.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-angulars-apply-digest/

> The $digest cycle starts as a result of a call to $scope.$digest(). Assume that you change a scope model in a handler function through the ng-click directive. In that case AngularJS automatically triggers a $digest cycle by calling $digest(). When the $digest cycle starts, it fires each of the watchers. These watchers check if the current value of the scope model is different from last calculated value. If yes, then the corresponding listener function executes

P.S Why not use $interval ?

Comment: Hmm. I tried using $interval, and I was receiving the same outcome.

I'm not sure how the $scope.digest() item relates, as the problem was that the  variable wasn't being updated at all, not that it was slow. 

However! I did figure out a solution. I'd love to hear your thoughts on it, though